# BaggingClassifier and CatBoost with categorical features don't work properly

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science, catboost

I want to run sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier with CatBoostClassifier as estimator but the thing is there are some categorical features and this cause such error:

> CatBoostError: 'data' is numpy array of floating point numerical type, it means no categorical features, but 'cat_features' parameter specifies nonzero number of categorical features

```
clf = CatBoostClassifier(task_type='GPU',
                         n_estimators=8000,
                         early_stopping_rounds=5,
                         verbose=250,
                         cat_features=['avg_day_of_week', 'avg_month', 'mode_subgroup', 'mode_small_group']
                        ) 

from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
bag_clf = BaggingClassifier(clf, n_estimators=10, max_samples=0.8)
bag_clf.fit(X_train.drop('client_id', axis=1), y_train)
```

Is it possible to overcome this problem?

Comment: See if you find some inspiration in this discussion: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/635

Comment: @ctenar, I didn't find any related to my problem information

Answer (score 0):

from catboost official documentation:
[why catboost cant handle NaNs from float type as categorical features:](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/faq.html#why-float-and-nan-values-are-forbidden-for-cat-features)

a simple workaround for your case would be to convert your numpy matrix as pd.dataframe:

```
bag_clf.fit(pd.DataFrame(X_train.drop('client_id', axis=1)), y_train)
```